# Servidor dedicado X VPS. Como saber qual se adequa a determinada situação?

Tags: php, servidor

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP (codeigniter + MySQL) hospedada em um ambiente web compartilhado. Os acessos de visualização e escrita em banco de dados aumentaram muito nos últimos tempos e estou tendo problemas de "estrangulamento" (CPU Throttling) por parte do servidor de hospedagem.

Cheguei ao ponto que tenho que mudar de servidor devido a lentidão que o site está sendo submetido. Tenho por volta de 10 mil pessoas conectadas ao mesmo tempo e desses conectados mais menos 8 mil gravam algo no banco de dados.

**Qual escolher entre Dedicados e VPS?**

Já li tanto sobre eles que fiquei confuso e gostaria de saber na prática de vocês.

Comment: acredito que você nem deva cogitar o Dedicado, afinal de contas, a melhor opção para você é ir para a nuvem, usando uma instância AWS EC2 ou o equivalente em outro fornecedor de cloud

Comment: Concordo com o @gpupo, existem muitas empresas boas e que te ajudam a escalar seu sistema conforme ele for crescendo. ([DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com), [Linode](http://linode.com), [Heroku](http://heroku.com), [AWS](http://http://aws.amazon.com), etc.)

Comment: Mas qual o motivo para usar a nuvem? Performance, segurança?

Comment: Obrigado pessoal. Abriram minha mente. Ainda estamos estudando a questao da nuvem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um servidor dedicado ou uma VPS vão lhe fornecer resultados aceitáveis, a diferença mesmo e que um servidor dedicado é uma máquina física e a VPS é uma máquina virtual.

Considero uma VPS uma opção melhor que um servidor de dedicado na maioria dos casos, pois seus recursos computacionais podem ser expandidos. Diferente dos dedicados que muitas vezes não tem disponibilidade para isso.

A performance de um dedicado e significantemente superior a de uma VPS, e o preço de manutenção também.

Então e o seu problema vem sendo o consumo compartilhado uma VPS irá resolver o seu problema, pois os recursos dela são dedicados, não tendo o problema da hospedagens compartilhadas.

[]'s

Answer (score 1):

Bem, antes vou lhe falar qual as diferenças:

Servidor Dedicado:
Os Servidores Dedicados são máquinas físicas, totalmente dedicadas com hardware de alta performance para comportar altas requisições.

VPS:
Um Servidor Dedicado fracionado.

Cloud Server:
Um Servidor Dedicado fracionado na nuvem, porem ele fica em um storage remoto, diferente do VPS ele não esta no HD local, muitas vezes ele pode ser migrado de um dedicado para outro sem ninguem notar, diferente do VPS que só fica em 1 dedicado.

VPS e Cloud Server tem a vantagem de poder adicionar ou remover memoria, cpu rapidamente.

recomendo cloud server.

Comment: Obrigado Felipe Gabriel. Voce sugere alguma empresa "cloud server" nos Estados Unidos?

Comment: Recomendo a Amazon